# cannot add web parts to page - sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I cannot add web parts to a web part page. If I click "Add web part" in a web part zone, there is a javascript error: Type mismatch, row 2, char. 13993, URI: http://portalsite/_layouts/wpadder.js?rev=hnGJJEMcU5XH%2BCq7PlSxJw%3D%3D
Is this a known bug? I tried more installations - no luck.
Thanks :)
Ravie.

Answer (score 1):

Ravie,
I have seen this kind of behavior before, it is usually a result of another javascript error. In other words something else on the page is causing a javascript error which is preventing the SharePoint javascript from running properly.

Try using Firefox or Chrome to edit the page they tend to be more tolerant javascript errors